# Array Unexpected Behavior

Tags: java, arrays

So I am trying to do a very simple task of taking two identical arrays and setting the first value of the first array to the last value of the second array.

The code below shows me trying to do so with the `numberArray` and `duplicateArray`. The bulk of the code however is me trying to figure out why I am getting a weird result.

```
System.out.print("Normal array 1: ");
for (int l = 0 ; l < numberArray.length ; l++){
    System.out.print(numberArray[l]);
}

System.out.print("Duplicate array 1: ");
for (int l = 0 ; l < duplicateArray.length ; l++){
    System.out.print(duplicateArray[l]);
}
System.out.println();

numberArray[0] = duplicateArray[duplicateArray.length - 1];

System.out.print("Duplicate array 2: ");
for (int l = 0 ; l < duplicateArray.length ; l++){
    System.out.print(duplicateArray[l]);
}
System.out.println();

System.out.print("Normal array 2: ");
for (int l = 0 ; l < numberArray.length ; l++){
    System.out.print(numberArray[l]);
}
```

This outputs:

```
Normal array 1: 123
Duplicate array 1: 123
Duplicate array 2: 323
Normal array 2: 323
```

What makes no sense to me is that even though I am supposedly setting the value one object to another, both are changing.

My understanding of Java is this:

```
array[x] = array2[y];
//value at index x of "array" now equals value at index y of "array 2"
//however, array2 should not be changed at all since it is just referenced in the above line of code, not mutated
```

Am I missing something really simple? I've been racking my brains trying to figure this out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

I have been asked to provide the declaration of my two arrays so here they are:

```
int[] numberArray = {1, 2, 3};
int[] duplicateArray = numberArray;
```

This shouldn't make a difference right? Setting one array to another shouldn't link them (or so I think).

Comment: Can you provide us declaration of this arrays? I guess that they both reference to the same object

Comment: your both array pointing to same array in memory

Comment: This is called **Aliasing** and happens, when two arrays point to the same reference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As i commented , your both array pointing to same array in memory

```
int[] numberArray = {1, 2, 3};
int[] duplicateArray = numberArray; // duplicateArray is just a another name for numberArray
```

so if you change any value with either of names `duplicateArray` or `numberArray` mean you are changing the array in memory  which is pointed by both.

So you need to create a new array by adding elements of `numberArray` to `duplicateArray` using `System.arraycopy`;

like this

```
int[] numberArray = {1, 2, 3};
int[] duplicateArray = new int[numberArray.length];
System.arraycopy( numberArray , 0, duplicateArray , 0, numberArray .length );
```

View the image for visual view

[image: visual representation of answer]

Comment: @Benjamin Lowry letme add something more , your will like it and your welcome Mr. Benjamin Lowry

Comment: If you want an exact copy of an array, you should use `array.clone()` instead of manually copying the elements.

Comment: @PavneetSingh thanks for the visual! That makes a lot of sense now.

Comment: @Tom ok i gonna do it, it feels good to be courteous but you are 100% right , it's done

Comment: @Clashsoft array.clone() can cause the same problem as well cuz it just copy the reference of one to another not element

Answer (score 0):

Previous answer is correct, to clarify, although the integer elements of the array are immutable, the array itself is not. Essentially, you have one array at two references; the 'duplicate' is not a duplicate object, just a duplicate reference.